# Automate Connection to VPN on startup

Tags: startup, vpn

I'm hoping to automate the startup of a VPN connection on startup of a CentOS 6.5 box. I have a Fortinet VPN client that I run on the command line as follows:

```
[centhost]$./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server 10.0.0.50:443 --vpnuser userxyz --keepalive
VPN Password:
Server certificate is invalid. Do you want to connect anyway? [y/n]
Connection successful.
Tunnel running.
```

My challenge with automating this connection is that I need to enter in a VPN password, and then accept the invalid certificate. Also, it seems that the VPN client continues to run as a user process once connected, not a daemon, which is fine, but I'll need it to keep running in the background. Also, when I do a ps aux | grep forti, I notice that it's not running just the one process, but actually four that are all the same, which is also fine. Just don't know if that impacts my options for automating. I'd also like to automatically restart the connection if it fails. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ps -auxf` would likely be better here for understanding the impact on automation.

Comment: **Expect:** http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35328_01/E35336/html/vmcli-script.html **Expect to VPN:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209953/connect-cisco-anyconnect-via-bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using this code (you have to install the `expect` package first):

I've installed `forticlientsslvpn_cli` in `/opt/forticlientsslvpn`. 
Replace `IP_FORTIGATE`, `PORT_FORTIGATE`, `VPN_USERNAME`, and `VPN_PASSWORD`
with your values.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set force_conservative 0  ;
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
            sleep .1
            exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}
set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000
send -- "cd /opt/forticlientsslvpn/\r"
send -- "./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server IP_FORTIGATE:PORT_FORTIGATE --vpnuser VPN_USERNAME"
expect -exact "./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server IP_FORTIGATE:PORT_FORTIGATE --vpnuser VPN_USERNAME"
send -- "\r"
expect -exact "\r
Password for VPN:"
send -- "VPN_PASSWORD\r"
expect -exact "\r
STATUS::Setting up the tunnel\r
STATUS::Connecting...\r"
send -- "Y\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to provide a reference for how to install `expect`, and a brief explanation of what it is doing.  Also, the question asks about automatically restarting the connection if it fails.  Does your answer address that?  If it does, I don't see it.  Please [edit] your answer to improve it; do not put your responses in comments.