# Can I trigger VPN connection based on online status?

Tags: networking, gnome3, networkmanager, vpn, gnome-shell

I use my machine (GNOME desktop) on my home wifi, at public wifi locations and with no wifi connection.

How can I set up a trigger so that as soon as my machine connects to the internet, it establishes my default VPN connection? In other words:

- as soon as I connect to my home wifi
- as soon as I connect to a public access point
- as soon as I log into a captive portal (at a public access point)

If it's possible to make the VPN connection permanently active but somehow "inert" when offline, that's also great.

Comment: not the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191106 which is triggered on startup

Comment: I'm not sure what the Gnome interface to NetworkManager looks like, but in KDE Plasma, each connection has an option to `Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection`.

Comment: related https://askubuntu.com/questions/967408/how-to-automatically-connect-to-vpn-in-ubuntu-17-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure your VPN password field is set to "Store the password for all users". This workaround is required even on a single-user system. [(See related bug.)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/network-manager/+bug/1624317)

Then, rather than using the GNOME system menu (in the top right corner) to edit your network settings, launch the `nm-connection-editor` GUI as follows:

1. From the command line: `nm-connection-editor &`
2. You will be given a list of all network connections, including your wifi and VPN connections.
3. Open any wifi connection and navigate to the *General* tab.
4. You will see the following option: "Automatically connect to VPN when using this connection".
5. Tick that option, and select your VPN from the associated dropdown.
6. Click "Save".

Repeat for every wifi connection that requires an automatic VPN connection. The next time you connect using one of these wifi connections, a VPN connection will be established at the same time.

**Note:** Some public access points require you to first log in via a captive portal. An automatic VPN attempt will fail, because you need to log into the portal first.